# Overloading operator new and exception correctness

Tags: c++, exception

While looking at legacy code I found something similar to the following code

```
void* legacy_type::operator new(size_t size) {
    return pool_alloc(size);
}
```

pool_alloc is known to never throw and return 0 in case of failure.

There is no overload for std::nothrow variant of new here.

I wonder whether this code is semantically correct and has well defined behavior.

Should `new (std::nothrow) legacy_type;` use custom pool_alloc? In my compiler it does not compile at all. Is it well defined behavior?

Should constructor run and crash due to `this==0` if overloaded `operator new` returns zero? In my compiler it runs (and crashes on member initialization). Is it standard well defined behavior?

Comment: The constructor shouldn't be called if the `operator new` returns a null pointer, and then the entire `new` expression will return a null pointer itself.

Comment: It is acceptable behavior in C++, but will crash if the class has a virtual table or a constructor that does not test `this==0` before accessing variable members. It is obviously not usual and should probably be avoided. You can try to just delete that definition and see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No it shouldn't. These are different functions. And, when you overload one of the operations - all other operations will never work, if they are not overloaded, since if there is `operator new` in class-scope and signature is not acceptable, then compiler will not search for global `operator new`, so, compile-error will happened.

2) You break postconditions, if your `new` will return null pointer.
n3376 18.6.1.1/3

> Required behavior: Return a non-null pointer to suitably aligned storage (3.7.4), or else throw a bad_-
> alloc exception. **This requirement is binding on a replacement version of this function.**

If you want to returns 0, you should use following signature

```
void* operator new(size_t) throw()
```

if you use this overloading and returns 0 from it, there is no seg-fault.

n3376 5.3.4/13

> If the
> allocation function returns null, initialization shall not be done, the deallocation function shall not be called,
> and the value of the new-expression shall be null.